# How to stop Maven from expanding env. variable w/Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, environment-variables

I'm familiar with Jenkins, but new to Maven, and I'm trying to figure out how to stop our Maven jobs in Jenkins from expanding an environment variable inside of the `ApplicationContext.xml` file.

Inside our `ApplicationContext.xml` file we reference a `${DeployMode}` environment variable (that we created) which Tomcat expands at load/run time:

```
<!-- SPRING CONTEXT static accessor -->
<beans:bean id="contextApplicationContextProvider"
            class="com.dartneuroscience.compserv.rest.appcontext.AppContextProvider">
  <beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:value>${DeployMode}</beans:value>
  </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="placeholderConfig"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <beans:property name="location"
                  value="/WEB-INF/App_${DeployMode}.properties" />
</beans:bean>
```

The problem is that in a Maven build run by Jenkins, the built `WEB-INF/ApplicationContext.xml` looks like this if there's an environment variable set on the build machine (let's say to 'Prod' in this example):

```
<!-- SPRING CONTEXT static accessor -->
<beans:bean id="contextApplicationContextProvider"
            class="com.dartneuroscience.compserv.rest.appcontext.AppContextProvider">
  <beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:value>Prod</beans:value> <!-- Expanded env. var -->
  </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="placeholderConfig"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
  <beans:property name="location"
                  value="/WEB-INF/App_Prod.properties" /> <!-- Expanded env. var -->
</beans:bean>
```

And so the value is now "hard coded" into the WAR, and will always act like "Prod" even if the target web server has its `DeployMode` environment variable set to something else, like 'Staging'.

This does not happen when I run Maven manually on the same build server--it only happens when Jenkins builds the job.

Is there a setting I can pass to Jenkins to stop this behavior?

I've looked at options like the EnvInject Plugin to `UNSET` all environment variables as a job is run, but I am really puzzled by this behavior and would like to get to the bottom of it.

Thank you.

## Update 1

I found the following resource filtering block in the top-level POM and added the `<excludes/>` block to skip our `AppContext.xml` file:

```
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <webResources>
            <webResource>
              <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>*.xml</include>
              </includes>
              <excludes>
                <exclude>*AppContext.xml</exclude>
              </excludes>
              <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
            </webResource>
          </webResources>
```

But this still doesn't answer why the environment variables are added to the properties list when run by Jenkins, and ignored when run from the command line; though I did find this Hudson issue from a couple of years ago: [Resource filtering fails when run from Hudson](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-3715)

Also, EnvInjectPlugin does what it advertises, but in removing at least the PATH var, the build broke because maven could not find the `ls` command.

## Update 2

Changing the job in Jenkins from a "Maven 2/3 project" to a "Free-style software project" and using the `Invoke top-level Maven targets` build step produces the desired result without having to modify the POM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins may be enabling resource filtering somehow.  You have lots of choices for configuring filtering.  You may disable it entirely, limit filtering to files with certain extensions, tell it not to include build properties in the filters, or choose different delimiters to be filtered entirely.  See the [resources:resources docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html) or the [description of resource filtering concepts](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  It was a resource filtering issue, please see my update above.