# Disable Jenkins Variable Expansion

Tags: jenkins

It looks like Jenkins (2.113) is replacing the string `${USER}` in some of my shell scripts with `jenkins`.

This makes sense, as I certainly see more people asking about how to write Jenkins variables into output files, but in this case I'd like it to leave those files alone -- the scripts break if they try to run under the (non-existent) "jenkins" user.

How do I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't fully understand why the behavior is occurring, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522857/how-to-stop-maven-from-expanding-env-variable-w-jenkins) led me in the right direction.

If I convert my project from a Maven Project to a Freestyle Project which manually calls `mvn clean deploy` I get a compiled project without Jenkins, or perhaps some component of Maven, replacing a bunch of variables in shell scripts.

Also, despite having the same version of Maven on my Jenkins box as locally, I had to alter a few minor settings in my pom.xml to get the Jenkins-Maven to clean deploy even though the same files would clean deploy on my development machine. But that's a separate mystery that I can live without solving.